# Invalid charachter Error while trying to write JTable contents into XML

Tags: java, xml

I need to write the contents of a JTable into a XML file which has nested elements, but when I do, I get `DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified` Below is my class that handles XML stuff:

```
package com.example.csvapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

/**
 *
 * @author Wojtek
 */
public class XMLAdapter {
    Map<String, Integer[]> elemTags;
    String [] headers;
    
    
    public XMLAdapter()
    {
        elemTags = new HashMap<>();
        headers = new String[]{"manufacturer", "size", "resolution", "type", "touch", "name",
        "physical_cores", "clock_speed", "ram ", "storage", "type", "name",
        "memory", "os", "disc_reader"};
    }
    
    public String writeXML(TableModel table)
    {
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document d = dBuilder.newDocument();
            
            Element root = d.createElement("laptops");
            d.appendChild(root);
            
            for(int i=0; i<table.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                Element rows = d.createElement("laptop");
                root.appendChild(rows);
                Attr attr = d.createAttribute("id");
                attr.setValue((i+1)+"");
                rows.setAttributeNode(attr);
                for(String key: elemTags.keySet())
                {
                    Element elem = d.createElement(key);
                    rows.appendChild(elem);
                    if(elemTags.get(key).length==3)
                    {
                        String attrName="";
                        if(key.equals("screen"))
                        {
                            attrName="touch";
                        }
                        if(key.equals("disc"))
                        {
                            attrName="type";
                        }
                        Attr a=d.createAttribute(attrName);
                        a.setValue(table.getValueAt(i, elemTags.get(key)[2]).toString());
                        elem.setAttributeNode(a);
                    }
                    for(int j=elemTags.get(key)[0];j<=elemTags.get(key)[1];j++)
                    {
                        Element el = d.createElement(headers[j]);
                        elem.appendChild(el);
                        String value="";
                        if(table.getValueAt(i, j)!=null)
                        {
                            value = table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
                        }
                        el.appendChild(d.createTextNode(value));
                    }
                }
            }
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer t = tFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(d);
            StreamResult result;
            
            try
            {
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File("katalog.xml"));
                result = new StreamResult(fos);
                t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                t.transform(source, result);
                try
                {
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    return e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e)
        {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        catch(DOMException e)
        {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return "Zapisono do XML";
    }
    
    public void MapTags()
    {
        elemTags.put("manufacturer", new Integer[]{0,0});
        elemTags.put("screen", new Integer[]{1,3,4});
        elemTags.put("processor", new Integer[]{5,7});
        elemTags.put("ram", new Integer[]{8,8});
        elemTags.put("disc", new Integer[]{9,9,10});
        elemTags.put("graphic_card", new Integer[]{11,12});
        elemTags.put("os", new Integer[]{13,13});
        elemTags.put("disc_reader", new Integer[]{14,14});
    }
}
```

Also, that's what the XML file should look like:

```
<laptops moddate="2015-10-30 T 10:15">
  <laptop id="1">
    <manufacturer>Asus</manufacturer>
    <screen touch="no">
      <size>12"</size>
      <resolution>1600x900</resolution>
      <type>matte</type>
    </screen>
    <processor>
       <name>i7</name>
       <physical_cores>8</physical_cores>
       <clock_speed>3200</clock_speed>
    </processor>
    <ram>8GB</ram>
    <disc type="SSD">
       <storage>240GB</storage>
    </disc>
    <graphic_card>
       <name>intel HD Graphics 4000</name>
       <memory>1GB</memory>
    </graphic_card>
    <os>Windows 7 Home</os>
   <disc_reader>Blu-Ray</disc_reader>
 </laptop>
 <laptop id="2">
   <manufacturer>Dell</manufacturer>
   <screen touch="yes">
      <size>16"</size>
      <resolution>1376x768</resolution>
      <type/>
   </screen>
   <processor>
     <name>i5</name>
     <physical_cores>4</physical_cores>
     <clock_speed/>
   </processor>
   <ram>16GB</ram>
   <disc>
      <storage>120GB</storage>
   </disc>
   <graphic_card>
      <name>intel HD Graphics 5000</name>
      <memory>2GB</memory>
   </graphic_card>
   <os>Windows Vista</os>
   <disc_reader>no</disc_reader>
 </laptop>
</laptops>
```

I don't know what's causing this, I tried removing spaces etc., but that didn't work, so now I'm stumped. Does anyone know what's the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're doing `toString` on arrays, which will give you characters `[` and `@` for one thing. You probably need `Arrays.toString`

Comment: No, ```Arrays.toString``` can't have ```table.getValueAt(i, j)``` as a parameter, since it's not an object, not an array

Comment: @MrGerwant Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Sorry. Ignore that comment. I missed the array indexing

Comment: I used ```System.out.println(el);``` to see what's inside the object - and it turns out it's all nulls, despite the fact that ```el.getTextContent()``` has the correct value. I've changed ```el.appendChild(d.createTextNode(value));``` to ```el.setTextContent(value);```, but it's all the same.

Comment: Apperently, adding ```.trim()``` in ```appendChild()``` paramether fixed it